# How to implement Conv1DTranspose (Keras)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I want to build a generator model based on the picture ([reference](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3410530.3414367)).
The picture said that the model is using a 1D-Transposed Convolutional Layer.

[image: generator model]

Is that possible to build the model (like in the picture) by using **Conv1DTranspose** in Keras while the input size is **(10x10x1)**?
If it is possible, could you give some advice on how to perform it in Keras?
Thank you.

Before, I tried to build the model. The dimension output seems to be correct, but I used Conv2DTranspose instead of Conv1DTranspose. (please correct me if I am wrong on the implementation **especially on the first 4 layers**).

```
def get_mlp():
    in_lat = Input(shape=(100,))
    
    x = Reshape((10,10,1))( in_lat )   
    x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 7, strides=(2,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(64, 7, strides=(2,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(128, 7, strides=(2,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    
    x = Reshape((800,-1))(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 3, strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(64, 3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    
    out = Dense(100, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(in_lat, out)
    
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Output

```
Model: "functional_95"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_64 (InputLayer)        [(None, 100)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_80 (Reshape)         (None, 10, 10, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_91 (Conv2DT (None, 20, 10, 32)        1600      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_92 (Conv2DT (None, 40, 10, 64)        100416    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_93 (Conv2DT (None, 80, 10, 128)       401536    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_81 (Reshape)         (None, 800, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, 800, 128)          49280     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_48 (Conv1D)           (None, 400, 64)           24640     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_49 (Conv1D)           (None, 200, 32)           6176      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 200, 100)          3300      
=================================================================
Total params: 586,948
Trainable params: 586,948
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 
I did not get any errors when I implemented it. However, I am still not sure about the first 1D-Transposed Layers  because I used 2D-Transposed Layers on my code. Do you have any advices for it ?

Comment: @FranzP:Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061208/how-to-implement-the-conv1dtranspose-in-keras)  and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1DTranspose)

Comment: Thanks for the references